# How Do I Keep My Content Area From Moving

Tags: javascript, html, css

So the issue stems from my content area simply trying to extend beyond the page width and so it moves down. If I set it to auto, it will continue to do so. I can set max width to something less than the space the nav bar takes up minus room for the whitespace between the two, but it will break upon resizing the window.

I have javascript in place to set the width and height minimums to percentages of the screen space as to prevent breaks. There is a lot of work in progress still but the biggest issue is getting the content area to simply remain to the side of the nav bar and have the nav bar and content able to extend beyond the screen. Say the content ends up going about two screen lengths down. I want the nav bar to continue down with it. How do I do this and keep my content area from jumping below the navbar?

Here are some photos of the issue.

https://imgur.com/a/LLGhzcT

Here is most of the code for the html, javascript, and css. For some reason JSFiddle doesn't appreciate it but it all works just fine in the actual web page. I use Laravel as my PHP Framework so again, the code is more along the lines of:

@extend ("shared/layouts/topbar") // the code for the top bar
etc.

https://jsfiddle.net/D3FAULTJ3ST3R/4h0jqr1g/6/

jsfiddle doesn't like trying to load my screen size function or my toggle side bar function and for whatever reason I can't even get the sidebar to appear in jsfiddle. But from the photos you can see, the side  bar works just fine except it's not extending beyond the screen in the event the content goes lower.

I've tried different displays such as flex, inline, and others. I've tried to make them part of the same divs. I've tried getting rid of the extensions and putting them all in the same html file.

HTML:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" onload="setScreenSize()">
<div id="topbar" class="topbar" style="background-color: blue">

    <div id="sidebar-share" class="sidebar-share">

        <div id="sidebar-toggler" class="sidebar-toggler" onclick="toggleSidebar()">
            &#9776;
        </div>

        <a href="http://portalx.XXXXXXXX.net/portalx">
            <div id="apx-label" class="apx-label">
                Portal X
            </div>
        </a>

    </div>

    <a href="http://portalx.XXXXXXXX.net/portalx">

        <div id="app-name" class="app-name">

        </div>

    </a>

</div>

<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar" style="background-color: blue">
    <div id="profile-block" class="profile-block">

    </div>
</div>

<div id="contentarea" class="contentarea" style="background-color: red">
    <h1 style="clear: both;"> Yelp asdfasdfasdfsadassjfldkj;asdlkfjalks;djflkajsdlfkja;lksdfjlkajasdlfmhklajsdkfljaskld;jflkasjdflkjasl;kdfjajsd;lkfjlkasjdfsdfkjalksd;fjalksdjfl;kajsdlk;fal;ksdjflkasjdlf;kjalsk;dfjlka;sjdflk;jasld;kfjla;skdjf;lkajsdflkjaslkd;fja;lskdjfl;kasjdfdf aklsjd;;;;;;lksdjflkjalskdjfklkjlsdl;kfjlkasdjfjas;lkdjfklj;aslkdjflajs;dfjk;asjd;lfjaklsdfj</h1>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
/* Portal X CSS */

/*
    Programmer: XXXXXXX
    Created:    07/17/2019
    Intention:  This will be the css file used by the master
                layout.
*/

/* CSS for Everything */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  white-space: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
}

/* CSS for Content Area */

.contentarea {
    height: 95%;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
}

/* CSS for Top Bar Objects */

.topbar {
    height: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.sidebar-share {
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
}

.sidebar-toggler {
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.apx-label {
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: arial, serif;
}

/* CSS for Side Bar Objects */

.sidebar {
    height: 95%;
  width: 3%;
    float: left;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

a, a:visited {
    color: inherit;
}

.profile_img {
    width:85px;
    height:85px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
/* Portal X Javascript */

/*
    Programmer: XXXXXXX
    Created:    07/17/2019
    Intention:  This is the javascript for the master layout of Portal X.
*/

function toggleSidebar() {

    if(document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width == "10%") {
        var sideWidthMin = screen.width * (3/100);
        var maxContent = screen.width - sideWidthMin - 4;

        document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "3%";
        document.getElementById("sidebar").style.minWidth = sideWidthMin;

        document.getElementById("contentarea").style.maxWidth = maxContent;
    }
    else {
        var sideWidthMin = screen.width * (1/10);
        var maxContent = screen.width - sideWidthMin - 4;

        document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "10%";
        document.getElementById("sidebar").style.minWidth = sideWidthMin;

        document.getElementById("contentarea").style.maxWidth = maxContent;
    }
}

function setScreenSize() {

    var topHeightMin = screen.height * (5/100);
    var sideWidthMin = screen.width * (1/10);
    var maxContent = screen.width - sideWidthMin - 4;
    var toggleWidth = sideWidthMin * (3/10);
    var apxWidth = sideWidthMin * (7/10);

    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.minWidth = toggleWidth;
    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "3%";
    document.getElementById("topbar").style.minHeight = topHeightMin;
    document.getElementById("sidebar-share").style.minWidth = sideWidthMin;
    document.getElementById("sidebar-toggler").style.minWidth = toggleWidth;
    document.getElementById("apx-label").style.minWidth = apxWidth;
}
```

Comment: Curious why you are using JS to do all of this styling and screen width checking, when it seems you could use CSS `flexbox` or `grid` and `media` queries to handle responsiveness?

Comment: The main reason being that I simply couldn't get it to work properly with the way Laravel handles extensions and yields. I couldn't get it to flow properly. The way it's structured in my Laravel project follows as so:

APP FILE
<? php 
@extends('shared/layouts/master')
@section('content')

Master File

    <? php
(Bunch of stuff)
@extends('shared/layouts/content')
@extends('shared/layouts/sidebar')
@extends('shared/layouts/topbar')

Comment: @disinfor I've decided to just mess with the laravel layout a bit as I couldn't get the extended layouts to properly work. So I changed them to include and thus far haven't seen anything break due to that but it did allow for the flexboxs to work properly. Now everything looks BEAUTIFUL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to just mess with the laravel layout a bit as I couldn't get the extended layouts to properly work. So I changed them to include and thus far haven't seen anything break due to that but it did allow for the flexboxs to work properly.